# Next.js - how to use localStorage during initial render

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a switch between light/dark themes with state saved in localStorage.

I want the initial render in browser to be with the correct theme.

This is my code which works (in a 'use client' component):

```
export default function useDarkSide() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localStorage?.theme || 'light')
  ...
}
```

but the issue is that Next.js also tries rendering this on server and throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

how do I solve this? I don't want to call localStorage from useEffect because that's too late (first client side render of the page is rendered with default light theme and only afterwards it switches to dark...)

i want to avoid the flicker between the light and dark themes...

Comment: Then `'use client'` for the theme switcher.

Comment: it is a 'use client' component, but use client components are still rendered on server...

Comment: You should include the entire file. Are you bringing in `use client`?

Comment: of course, otherwise I could not do useState

Comment: i solved it using cookies which allows me to render the theme on server using SSR and avoid the flicker

Answer (score 0):

Check for local storage in useEffect then set the theme

Comment: have you read the question at all?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).